# Using socket to connect over Internet on Android device

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

How to connect to Android device using sockets over Internet?
On local network works fine, I can connect and send messages.
I thought when I bound a local ip address to the socket would be enough to accomplish that.

Comment: You should have external static IP address to achieve that. If you use your mobile device in local network, add port forwarding to your router and connect from web to router's IP. If you use it on cellular network, things going badlier. You need some kind of redirect then, maybe like public server with vpn, to which you phone should always connect when gains network.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment kinda crossed my mind. I'll look another way.